# Writing __fish_is_first_arg, but includes the arg's parameter

Tags: fish

I'm writing a completions file for [cwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp), Google's to-webp converter. Its help says that `-preset` should come before all other arguments. With that in mind, I tried restricting its availability with `__fish_is_first_arg`, like this:

```
complete -c cwebp -x -n '__fish_is_first_arg' -o preset -a 'default photo picture drawing icon text' -d 'Preset setting'
```

This would make it so `cwebp -o -pres<Tab>` would *not* suggest `-preset`, which is what I wanted.

Meanwhile, `cwebp -pres<Tab>` would fill out the argument to its full `-preset`, which is also what I wanted.

However, when I press the Tab key at `cwebp -preset <Tab>`, the only suggestions given are the files and directories in the current directory. This is not what I wanted.

---

With this in mind, I figured I had to write a "is first or second option" function. However, it's not going well. Here's what I have so far:

```
function __fish_cwebp_is_first_option_or_its_argument
    set -l tokens (commandline -co)
    # line alpha
    switch (count tokens)
        case 1
            return 0
        case 2
            if test \( "$tokens[2]" = '-preset' \)
                return 0
            end
            return 1
        case '*'
            # line beta
            breakpoint
            return 1
    end
end
```

This function body, as far as I can tell, works the same way as `return 0` (`(true)`). No matter what, `-pres<Tab>` completes to `-preset`, even when the line looks like `cwebp -h -H -version -pres<Tab>`.

When I put a breakpoint on line alpha, I can `echo $tokens` and see all the tokens that I've totally typed out (there needs to be at least one space between the last token and the cursor). However, when I have only a breakpoint on line beta as shown here, I can't even get the breakpoint to trigger. Not even with `cwebp -h -H -version -pres<Tab>` as mentioned above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch (count tokens)`

should be:

`switch (count $tokens)`

(For others reading this: the $ activates variable expansion. `count $tokens` expands the variable `tokens` and counts its values, while `count tokens` counts only the single literal "tokens").

Comment: I figured that if `switch` wasn't working right I must've missed something elementary. Thanks!